# mobileconfig file adding access to location services

Tags: ios, ipad, core-location, profile

We have an Enterprise app which needs to use Core Location. Our Ipad which will be distributed to our employees has some built in apps successfully "locked" out for certain apps, like Safari and Camera, et al. We do allow other built in apps such as mail and contacts and maps which is my problem at the moment. The Maps will load but it shows only a blank grid. No Map and location manager fails as shown in the error below.

Some one else create the profile and made the changes to the iPad. This person is unreachable and I have been given the challenge to fix it. I'm guessing it has something to do with the mobileconfig file because when I deleted it from a test iPad, all was well. I need to update the mobileconfig file but have no idea what to do to allow location updates. We do have a specific server we connect to, but like I said it works on the test iPad that does not have the mobileConfig profile installed. Please HELP!
Thanks

The message I get is:

> Nov  6 11:45:23 iPad locationd[40] : PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x1d687fc0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gs-loc.apple.com/clls/wloc, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gs-loc.apple.com/clls/wloc, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x1d67c020 "Could not connect to the server."}
>     Nov  6 11:45:23 iPad locationd[40] : NETWORK: no response from server, reachability, 2, queryRetries, 2
>     Nov  6 11:45:37 iPad Aerobics[117] : location manager failed with location: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the new .mobileconfig profile was not the cause, or it was but not directly. I needed to logon to our server and establish connection with location manager, then logon to our private server and do it again which included a compass error but fixed that by waving the ipad around - lol. Spent a full day trying to resolve this so I hope it helps someone.
Thanks to all who looked into my issue.